# InvalidOperationException using linq in untity3D

Tags: linq, unity-game-engine

I'm getting this weird exception when I call some routines written also in .NET 2.0 there are some Linq functions like Max and Where. These routines works fine when I tested it in a console application also set on .NET 2.0 and that's what I call it weird.
The erro description in unity is the next.
[image]

I just instanse the class in a unity event button. Here's how I call the class that are doing the routines. Unity.

```
Routines bww = new Routines(ListOfItems());
bww.main();
```

That's all. List of items is al method that returns some harcoded items for test purposes. And now the only two Linq statements i'm using are.

```
    public List<Elements> GetAllXs(int level)
    {
        var elementx = element.Where(w => w.level == level && w.orientacion == "X");
        return elementx.ToList();
    }

    public List<Elements> GetAllYs(int level)
    {
        var elementsy = elements.Where(w => w.level == level && w.orientacion == "Y");
        return elementsy.ToList();
    }
```

This code is from the library. I don't get what and where is the issue because it just does not works in unity. Params in CalcularCargas method are passed as out param.

```
CalcularCargas(out ipanelx, out ipanely);
```

Comment: Uh, what exactly is `CalcularCargas()` doing? I suspect it may be difficult to debug a method without being shown its body first. It's possible that the collection being used with `.Max()` is empty, or something like that.